# esper controlling event counts

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I have used esper to join streams as:
[image]

Now consider a scenario:
1. Two trades entered into system
2. Price arrived

In this scenario Grouping stream will generate two outputs one each for a trade. And this will also trigger two events out from final output. As no of events increases no of output events will also increase.
Now if a trade with 
Id - 03
Symbol - GOOG
Quantity - 300
 is entered into system, it will also triger 3 new events as %ageMV is also changed for each Id. As no of events increases it becomes difficult to handle on UI.

So my question is - 
**Is there any standard way of doing this?**

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to look into unidirectional joins and subqueries.

Comment: I have already used unidirectional joins on GROUPING and FINAL OUTPUT statements. Let me clarify my question: Any change from OrderFeed or PriceFeed will trigger all datarow from FinalOutPut streams as one of column (%ageMV) will be changed. So a set of 10000 rows will be triggered for each of the event either from OrderFeed or PriceFeed